# How to use nested templates in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have root selector:

```
<body>
    <my-app>
        Loading...
    </my-app>
</body>
```

In him loaded component with template:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
               <p>It is nested content:</p>
               <div class="content">
                   <nested-selector></nested-selector> 
               </div>`
})
```

Now I want to download the content in `nested-selector`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'nested-selector',
    template: `<p>{{content}}</p>`
})

export class Mycomponent{
   public content = "qwerty12345";
}
```

As a result, appended in the end an string:

```
<nested-selector _ngcontent-rbv-2="">qwerty12345</nested-selector>
```

As a result, we get the following page:

```
<body>
    <my-app>
        <p>It is nested content:</p>
        <div class="content">
           <nested-selector></nested-selector> 
        </div>
      <nested-selector _ngcontent-rbv-2="">qwerty12345</nested-selector>
    </my-app>
</body>
```

Although page should look like this:

```
<body>
    <my-app>
        <p>It is nested content:</p>
        <div class="content">
           <nested-selector>qwerty12345</nested-selector> 
        </div>
    </my-app>
</body>
```

Why is this happening? Why he creates a new selector? How to make it work properly?

**EDIT:**
I attached the main project files to uncover the essence of the problem: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/DsDpXG72bjpyaWfPc1S0?p=preview

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because your HTML is invalid in some way. Angular is quite picky and doesn't work with HTML that is invalid but the browser would accept. For example in `MyApp` component you use `'` (single quote) instead of ``` (backtick) for multiline string. Not sure if this is related to the problem though.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, In fact, I use templateUrl. Not a problem in quotes

Comment: I see. But it has to be somewhere else then in the code you provided, otherwise the Plunker would show the same behavior.

Comment: I still do not understand why he behaves

Comment: See the Plunker in my answer. It shows the desired behavior. Can you try to modify the Plunker to get the faulty behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you HTML is invalid.

`.`

[I tried to reproduce in this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V0Em5r?p=preview) but it shows the desired behavior.

Comment: I attached the main project files to uncover the essence of the problem.  I'm not sure that things are in the validity of HTML. You can look at this?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bza2fLKhdhimb01pMVpSTktQVlk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I won't download arbitrary zip files. Just use the Plunker and extend it with  your code until you can reproduce.

Comment: Try to create a fork first. I'm not very familiar with Plunker myself.

Comment: It seems to have happened to upload on plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/DsDpXG72bjpyaWfPc1S0?p=preview

Comment: Looks more like broken imports, not related to your question. Check the browser console output.

Comment: In the console, there is nothing, only: `Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode () to enable the production mode.` And this warnings: `DEPRECATION WARNING: 'enqueueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use addTask/addRepeatingTask/addMicroTask
 DEPRECATION WARNING: 'dequeueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use removeTask/removeRepeatingTask/removeMicroTask`

Comment: I get a dozen `Failed to load resource: the server responded with status of 404 () ...` I have no idea how to proceed. I looked at the HTML you added but couldn't find anything that's likely to cause the problem.

Comment: Maybe this is because I put on Plunker part of the project. In that console "Network": http://i66.tinypic.com/257ejqs.png

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I don't know that "feature"

Comment: Now I added `LocalizationComponent` in "directives" file `main/component.ts`. When loading the home page `localizationList.html` localization file content is downloaded to where i want. But when I turn on the link `/localization/` - happen problem of a described in question.  This means new content does not see the selectors? Why is that?